# Слетают стили при категории url

Tags: php

Смотреть  фото.
Роутер кастыль

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uri = explode("/", $url);

switch ($uri[1]) {
    case search:
        include 'src/views/Header.html';
        break;
```

Единая точка входа .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond {%REQUEST_URL$} !-f
RewriteCond {%REQUEST_URL$} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L,QSA]
DirectoryIndex index.php [L,QSA]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это дело исправить ?
Может роутер какой нибудь простой посоветуйте , если так не вариант сделать .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего стили слетают из-за неправильного пути в `HTML` коде. Перепроверьте

У вас так:

```
<link href="папки/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

А должно быть так:

```
<link href="/папки/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Капец, из-за одного слеша не работало, сходу и не подумаешь сразу на это.